# query PHP does not give errors but does not update the info

Tags: php, mysql

I've been searching questions about but unfortunatelly withotr success. The issue is that the folowing query in php to update a row does not work and gives no error, but when try the query in SQL (mysql) directly works fine... Could someone see where the error is?

query:

```
include('conexion.php');

$id_recibo=$_POST["id_recibo"];
$id_usuario=$_POST["id_usuario"];
$id_estado='2';

mysqli_query("UPDATE recibo SET id_estado = '$id_estado' WHERE id_recibo = '$id_recibo'");
```

Comment: I bet in your search you found plenty of "it does not work" with lack of detail too, no?

Comment: is there any error showing while you run code?

Comment: RTFM --> http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Side note: You should really read up on [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), your code is currently susceptible to SQL-Injection attacks.

Comment: Ok, can you show your `conexion.php` file?

Comment: the conexion works correctly as is the same file as I use in other pages that work correct. The issue is that no error is given by mysqli and the query is correct as I put directly the query at the data base and updates the row...

Comment: you need to use `prepare statements` and `bind parameter` for prevent SQL  injection. Follow this structure: `$update = $db->prepare("
    UPDATE recibo 
    SET id_estado = :id_estado
    WHERE id_recibo = :id_recibo
   ");
  $update->bindParam(':id_estado', $id_estado);
  $update->bindParam(':id_recibo', $id_recibo);
  $update->execute();`

Comment: Thank you Rimon, I will check the code to avoid sql injection.

Comment: See what @Qirel posted. Look at Procedural style. Follow the dupe close link (at the top of your question) and implement what YCS shows. Show all that (or you probably won't need to as it will solve your problem).